# POST request with data in node.js

Tags: javascript, post, request, node.js

How could I send POST request with data (eg. some variables) to the https server and display the results to the end user?

Comment: Use AJAX! (also, please provide some more details about what you're trying to do :) )

Comment: So this node.js script is running on a server in the middle of the two?

Comment: It is implementation of some rest API, and for authentication I need to ask API server for permission token, I need to use POST request with some secret ID so it is not possible to use AJAX (it has to be done on server side without any client integration)

Comment: @Spiny Norman: node.js does not know what AJAX is. It is a client-side concept. AJAX requests are handled like every other request(server-side).

Comment: Ah, right. Please disregard my comment: I didn't know about node.js and was assuming it was just some javascript file :$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `http.Client` module. From the docs:

```
var http = require('http');
var google = http.createClient(80, 'www.google.com');
var request = google.request('GET', '/', {'host': 'www.google.com'});
request.end();
request.on('response', function (response) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

I am pretty sure that you can exchange `GET` with `POST` ;)

Comment: ok, and how to send the data here? I know that I have to set 'security' arg to 'true' in createClient() for https, but I have no idea how to send data.

Comment: @qqryq: Use `request.write`. `request` is a `http.ClientRequest` object. The [docs](http://nodejs.org/api.html#http-clientrequest-196) tell you everything you need.

Comment: @qqryq: Did you read the docs? Did you call everything in the right order? "it does not work" is not a sufficient error description.

Comment: yes, i read the DOCs before I create that question in here, maybe I just didn't understand something. I use request.write after that google.request() and before request.end but the server I'm connecting to behaves like there were no data in the request.

Comment: @qqryq: Are you sure that you're sending the correct data? Check encoding and format.

Comment: you might need to add the "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header to your POST as well.

Comment: ok, error was in documentation of the API I wasimplementing, not in node.js implementation, sorry for making mes in here.

Comment: @qqryq "i fixed it, but I'm not going to post how I fixed it" = fuuuuuuuu. Can you please post your corrected code/explain what was wrong?